# want to save time when user connected to wifi

Tags: android, logging, time, wifi

Hi i want to save the time or more simply log of user's time "when he uses wifi?" can we get this information from OS log that what time user was connected and disconnected to wifi ?

Comment: you can register a receiver for network connection and you will receive notifications when the connection state changes. And yes, you can then log anything you want

Comment: how do you register the receiver ?

Comment: You can refer to the _Determining and Monitoring the Connectivity Status_ link in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [BradcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) in connection with an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) for the CONNECTIVITY_CHANGED broadcast (which requires the permission ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) and check the WiFi state in the IntentServicce and log it (see: [Determining and Monitoring the Connectivity Status](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Android broadcasts the network state, so you can listen for the messages using a `BroadcastReceiver`. More about it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html). Hope this helps.